# Cannot Login Admin Page

Tags: orchardcms

I have tried a lot of settings, WebMatrix vs Build from source code, sql vs sql compact version. Different version of Orchard.

But they all have the same problem: **Fail to login** 
When you accesss

```
http://localhost:43327/admin
```

Even password/username view cannot be loaded.
Address bar is showing:

```
http://localhost:43327/Users/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you define a machine key, as described in the release notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the theme, @Model.Content was not there.
Not view for Login will show up..

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user specified in the connection string does has the access to the database. 
Are you using a connectionstring with UserId and Password or using Integrated Security?